# How to play the sound of a video

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a podcast with images in, and I just want the sound of it. I have thought that I could develop a little iOS app to only play the music in videos. The problem is that I'm a beginner on Objective-C, and I'd like the help of the "pro" people. Is my app possible to realize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but we won't do your work for you.

Once you've learnt the basics, it shouldn't be hard to implement what you want using the AV Foundation framework.

If you get stuck, you're welcome to ask for help here, but remember: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com.

Comment: OK, thank you. I'll keep these things in mind! (I actually love challenges, but in this one I didn't know where to start!)